# QGIS view selected layers, manage views

Tags: qgis, layers, print-composer, viewer

I have a QGIS project with a large number of layers. Is it (without using Postgis) possible to define  "Views" which include different subsets of the layers?
For example: 
View 1: Layers WMS topographic, roads and villages
View 2: Blank background with only village outlines and existing sewer systems
etc.
This would come in handy because I have a number of print composers which are based on different selections of the layers. If I want to make a change to one of the print composers I have to remember which layers were visible when I locked the layers in the print composer.